# Numeric X axis for linechart

Tags: chart.js, linechart

I want to render a line chart with a set of (x,y) values. Both x axis and y-axis need to scaled. I mean say, I have values (1,10),(2,20),(4,30),(8,40) The distance between 1 and 2 should be half of between 2 and 4. Which in turn should be half of 4 and 8.

When I try with linechart now, since labels are just text, it shows me 1,2,4,8 with same gap between them.

Please check the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/y4p6fnts/)

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
var data = {
    labels: [1, 2, 4, 8],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",

        data: [10,20,30,40]
    }]
};
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Scatter chart extension (http://dima117.github.io/Chart.Scatter/) - listed under Community Extensions at http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-community-extensions.

This supports number scales.

Comment: Thank you :) this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 16):

If you wanted, you could use the `'scatter'` chart type (which was relatively recently introduced), or just override the default X-axis type to make it `'linear'` instead of the default `'category'` setting (`'time'` and `'logarithmic'` are other options).

However, if you take this approach, you will need to change your data format:

```
var data = {
    // No more "labels" field!
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",

        data: [{x:1,y:10},{x:2,y:20},{x:4,y:30},{x:8,y:40}] // Note the structure change here!
    }]
}
```

You will also need to make sure (if you continue using `'line'` as the chart type) that you override the options:

```
var options = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'linear',
            // ...
        }]
    }
}
```

There may be more steps required than are shown in this answer (I haven't mocked this up and I don't know your existing options), but these are the main steps.

Comment: I had a line plot before, and I can confirm that the only needed changes are having datapoints stored as {x:..., y:...} with added type: 'linear' in options. Also, there is no need to maintain data.labels, that field can be completely removed.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to update a array use in js :

```
var aChartDataMoy       = [];
for (i = 0; i < nbTamis; i++) {
            aChartDataMoy.push({
                'x': parseFloat(aTamis[i]),
                'y': parseFloat(aMoyenne[i])
            });   
}
```

and

```
datasets: [{
                    label: "Moyenne",
                    borderColor: 'rgb(229, 57, 53)',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    fill: false,
                    data: aChartDataMoy
                }
```